Prometheus Gauge throws System.Threading.LockRecursionException
I have some code that tracks the length of a queue, like this:
private static Gauge enqueuedWorkGauge = Metrics
        .CreateGauge(...);

public async Task ProcessMessageAsync(Task asyncWork)
{
        // increment counter because something is about to be added to the queue
        enqueuedWorkGauge
            .WithLabels(label1, label2)
            .Inc();

        // enqueue work; enqueueing might need to wait, so it is async
        var workCompletedTask = await queue.EnqueueWorkAsync(asyncWork);

        return workCompletedTask
            .ContinueWith(
                t =>
                {
                    // work is done!
                    // element is not in the queue anymore
                    enqueuedWorkGauge
                        .WithLabels(label1, label2)
                        .Dec();
                },
                default,
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
                TaskScheduler.Default
            );
}

Sometimes I can observe this exception in the logs:
System.Threading.LockRecursionException: Recursive read lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode.
         at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterReadLockCore(TimeoutTracker timeout)
         at Prometheus.Collector`1.TryGetLabelled(LabelSequence instanceLabels, TChild& child)
         at ProcessMessageAsync

For me it looks like the exception is thrown here: https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net/blob/master/Prometheus/Collector.cs#L341
Is this a bug in the prometheus .net library or do I use the tasks in a wrong way?
Thanks for help.
